# Show when I've voted

Tags: feature-request, voting

I often happen across posts that I've voted on. "Harrumph," I say to myself. "When?" I hover over the vote button, but alas it does not tell me anything.

Currently the flyover for the upvote button says "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear (click again to undo)"

The flyover for upvoted comments is "You've voted for this comment as a useful comment"

As a matter of curiousity, I'd like to know *when* I voted on the question, answer or comment via the flyover.

- *Don't suggest trying to click on it! It won't work when the question's been edited (the upvote will be undone)*

Comment: Why would you say "Harrumph" instead of "Eeek!" /joke